# FQL / Facebook API: retrieve list of all events i have marked

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

i was looking into the api docs but couldn't find a solution to my problem:
how can i query all events using fql which i marked in my own account (as maybe/attending)?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `event_member` table

`http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/`

Comment: i'm using this query which appears to be correct but doesn't return anything :(
SELECT name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description, eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())